# motorcycle battery correct voltage

Tags: kawasaki

motorcycle battery is 11.73 off and idling 12.09 is that to low?? Had the stator replaced 6  years ago. is that to soon for it to go out or is that normal. Bought the battery in October of 2016. Could it be charging system or a short somewhere? 
Thanks..

Comment: Has it been sitting unused for a long time? Has the battery been run completely flat previously?

Answer (score 2):

Both voltages are low. Could be a bad battery dragging down a good stator or a bad stator (or other charging system component) dragging down a good battery. Testing each separately would be a good idea. A shop will most likely charge and load test the battery for free or cheap. If the battery tests good, stick it back in the bike and check charging voltage at idle and with the engine running a bit faster. Ideally you want about 13.5-14.0 V, with a bit lower at idle being not unusual.